# Display SQLserv result as text in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I have a query where I'm already pulling back the results from a Sql query via an array as below.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT inc.STATUS as STATUS,
FROM dbo.HELP_DESK as inc";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$status=(
'1' => "Request For Authorization",
'3' => "Pending",
'4' => "Scheduled For Review",
'5' => "Scheduled For Approval",
'8' => "Pending",
);

echo "<table><tr id=\"header\"><td><center>Status</center></td><tr>";

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo "<tr><td><b><center> " . $row["STATUS"] . "</center></b></td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

sqlsrv_close( $conn );
?>
```

The `$row` fetches back a number from the database. However, I'm wanting to display the text from my $status array.

I've tried several methods but end up with a blank screen returned.

Any suggestions? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your while loop as below. check status number is available in `$status` or not if available then display its value otherwise display blank

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $status_str = isset($status[$row["STATUS"]])?$status[$row["STATUS"]]:"";
    echo "<tr><td><b><center> " . $status_str . "</center></b></td></tr>";
}
```

Also change your array to(You forgot `array` keyword)

```
$status=array(
'1' => "Request For Authorization",
'3' => "Pending",
'4' => "Scheduled For Review",
'5' => "Scheduled For Approval",
'8' => "Pending",
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read also about this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

```
strtr($row["STATUS"], $status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the the blank screen caused by a PHP error? You should check your logs.
Because, in your example, your wrote the array like this:

```
    $status=(
'1' => "Request For Authorization",
'3' => "Pending",
'4' => "Scheduled For Review",
'5' => "Scheduled For Approval",
'8' => "Pending",
);
```

But you have to use brackets instead:

```
$status=[
'1' => "Request For Authorization",
'3' => "Pending",
'4' => "Scheduled For Review",
'5' => "Scheduled For Approval",
'8' => "Pending",
];
```

Then you will have to display the the label by something like this:

```
echo $status[$row['STATUS']];
```

BTW, you should use a (micro) framework to develop, because you should (or must) not write a query in your DB and display the resuslts in the same file.

HTH.